# Query String in Javascript

Tags: javascript, query-string

How can we collect a query string value in javascript.
my script is like follows
http://192.168.10.5/study/gs.js?id=200
here i want to collect the id value in my gs.js script file.
 For this i am using

```
function getQuerystring(key, default_)
{
  if (default_==null) default_="";
  key = key.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]"+key+"=([^&#]*)");
  var qs = regex.exec(window.location.href);
  if(qs == null)
    return default_;
  else
    return qs[1];
}
var string_value = getQuerystring('id');
alert(string_value);
```

But it is not getting..Please anybody can correct me.Please

Answer (score 1):

From my [programming archive](http://www.guffa.com/Programming_archive.asp?id=16):

```
function querystring(key) {
  var re = new RegExp('(?:\\?|&)'+key+'=(.*?)(?=&|$)','gi');
  var r = [], m;
  while ((m = re.exec(document.location.search)) != null) r[r.length] = m[1];
  return r;
}
```

The function returns the found values as an array with zero or more strings.

Usage:

```
var values = querystring('id');
if (values.length > 0) {
  // use values[0] to get the first (and usually only) value
  // or loop through values[0] to values[values.length-1]
}
```

or:

```
var string_value = querystring('id').toString();
```

Answer (score 1):

This function gets the query string of the page hosting this script: it relies on `window.location.href`. It seems that `http://192.168.10.5/study/gs.js?id=200` is the address of the script itself and not the page. In order to do this you will need to first obtain this address by looking at the `script` tags in your document and then slightly modify the previous function to take an additional parameter representing the url and not relying on `window.location.href`.

Comment: Or - have the server side inject `var myid=200;` into the javascript code it serves for `gs.js?id=200`